# User can't connect to Azure SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created my first database (let's call it MyDB) on Azure and created a user that I want to use to query the DB from my applications. I only wanted to give that user `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader` because I think that is all this user needs to do from the application.

When I run this on MyDB:

```
SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,   
   isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName   
 FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
   ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
   ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
ORDER BY DP1.name;
```

I get this back:

```
db_accessadmin      No members
db_backupoperator   No members
db_datareader       MyDBUser
db_datawriter       MyDBUser
db_ddladmin         No members
db_denydatareader   No members
db_denydatawriter   No members
db_owner            dbo
db_securityadmin    No members
public              No members
```

so that seemed to work. The problem is - I have to give this user also Permission to connect to the DB in the first place, because when I try to connect to the server, I get this:

```
===================================

Cannot connect to abc.database.windows.net.

===================================

The server principal "MyDBUser" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyDBUser'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

I think this is probably, because my new user can't connect to master DB, as the errormessage suggests. However, when I look at the properties of MyDB, "Connect" was granted for the user by dbo

How can I let my user connect to the Azure DB Instance, preferably with as less permission as possible, I would only like for him to select, update, insert etc. on MyDB

I tried to change default DB with this command, so I don't need to do anything on masterDB, but the stored procedure wasn't found:

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='MyDBUser', @defdb='MyDB'
```

Edit: That's how I created the Login / User in SSMS

First (on instance):

```
CREATE LOGIN MyDBUser
    WITH PASSWORD = '******' 
GO
```

Then (on MyDB):

```
CREATE USER MyDBUser
    FOR LOGIN MyDBUser
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO

-- Add user to the database owner role
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'MyDBUser'
GO
```

Comment: If the instance is an Azure SQL Database, you need to create a `USER` within the database, not a `LOGIN`; databases in Azure SQL Databases are known as contained databases; they each have their own individual principles. Your error, and the fact you are using `sp_defaultdb` (which has been deprecated for ~10 years by the way) suggests you are using a `LOGIN` not a `USER`.

Comment: @Larnu it is a `USER` within the DB (in SSMS I see it right under Security > Logins under my instance. i also see it under Security > Users under MyDB). Sorry I'm not very experienced in SQLDB :(

Comment: That comment conflicts. if you are seeing the object under Security > Logins then it's a **`LOGIN`**. Database users are found in Security > Users within the database. Databases do *not* have a Login section under Security as `LOGIN`s are specifically for instances.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned  `sp_defaultdb` would not work against a `USER`; a `USER` doesn't have a default database as it's a database object. You have clearly created a `LOGIN` here not (or in addition to) a `USER`.

Comment: @Larnu I updated the question with how I created the User/Login. If I should delete that again and do something differently, can you tell me what and how? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: `CREATE USER MyDBUser FOR LOGIN MyDBUser` Crystall ball was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a `LOGIN` and then created a `USER` for the `LOGIN` but only in the database you want them to connect to but *not* in `master`.

SQL Azure Databases are contained databases, so there is no need to create a `LOGIN`; the databases use their own scoped credentials.

First `DROP` the `USER` and `LOGIN` you created. Connect to `MyDB` and `DROP` the user first:

```sql
DROP USER MyDBUser;
```

Then connect to `master` and `DROP` the `LOGIN`:

```sql
DROP LOGIN MyDBUser;
```

Now connect to `MyDB` again and `CREATE` the `USER` with the needed credentials:

```sql
CREATE USER MyDBUser WITH PASSWORD = N'Your Secure Password', DEFAULT_SCHEMA = N'dbo';
```

Then you can give it the needed database roles. *Don't* use `sp_addrolemember`; it has been deprecated for ~10 years.

```sql
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER MyDBUser;
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER MyDBUser;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I setup the user this way and ran a query on the database from PowerShell and it worked like a charm. Can't connect through SSMS though but I don't need to because for that I have my SQL Admin account. Perfect!

Comment: You need to define the database you are connecting to via SSMS, @SimonS , otherwise you'll be trying to authenticate as a `LOGIN` via `master`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error message when connecting to Azure SQL DB with SSMS. The solution there was to identify the database, hence the message "access the database "master"". You probably have entered the DB server name already.

You do not mention how you are trying to connect to the DB, but in case of SSMS, enter the name of the database on the tab "Connection properties" (available behind the "Options>>>" button on "Connect to Server" screen).